# How do I consume WCF Services with latest VS 2017 and Xamarin Android upgrades?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, visual-studio-2017

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Pro Version 15.4 along with Xamarin version 4.7.10.22 and Xamarin Android SDK Version 8.0.0.33.

When I try to use a Web Reference I added to my web service and call one of my service methods, I get the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure at
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke
```

When I go through the process of generating the contract file using the Silverlight 5.0 SDK's slsvcutil.exe, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation 'IsReadyAsync' contains a message 
with parameters. Strongly-typed or untyped message can be paired only with
strongly -typed, untyped or void message.
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.Validate(
System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od, System.Boolean isRpc,
System.Boolean isEncoded)
```

I have looked at the various forum mentions of consuming WCF services and it seems others have this struggle and since much of this information tends to be dated, I am asking for any guidance and help.

Thanks,

Bob